# Is it possible to set a query size limit quota for BigQuery ML (BQML)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

It's possible to set query size limits for BigQuery API on project and user-level, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

As I understand it, this includes BQML. The costs between BQ and BQML differ significantly, though. If we'd set a query size limit of 1 TB per user and day, this would allow the user to consume 1 TB with BQML, which results in costs of 250$, whereas for normal BQ query costs would be 5$.

Is there a way to set a user query size limit specifically for BQML?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for on-demand users there is no way to set a query limit specific for BQML CREATE MODEL statement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).